# How to check Guest user's log on os x?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, logs, guest-account

I leave my Mac at my job and when I come back, someone used it using Guest user.

Is there a way for me to check what this person did when he logged in my mac using Guest user?

Comment: NOPE, as soon s the guest user logs out all activity is deleted. You could set some parential controls to it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 is there any threat leaving a guest user enabled? Is there any threat for s/he that used this guest account install some virus?

Comment: Nope, Guest users do not have administrative rights, thus can not install. But they can look around (snupe) use the Internet ect...

Answer (score 1):

All data such as logs that would be stored within the user account's logs directory (~/Library/Logs) is deleted when the user logs out. Other than standard file recovery tools to recover the deleted logs, it's not possible to find out what the Guest user did—this is by design as the Guest user should leave no impact on the machine, and also attempts to stay disassociated from interaction from others.

Comment: NOPE, as soon s the guest user logs out all activity is deleted. You could set some parental controls to it. –  Buscar웃 6 hours ago

Comment: @Buscar What's your point? That's what I said